# How to Delete List Items That are Older Than X Days

Tags: list, workflow

What will be my best approach to delete an item that is older than x days?

If it is using a SharePoint workflow, how should I initiate the workflow and what are the steps involved in the workflow?

Or should I go with the option of using PowerShell?

Please help!!

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the version of SharePoint, etc. you could probably look into "Information Management Policy".

Here's a blog that introduces it:
[Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ecm/policy-and-retention-in-sharepoint-server-2010)